# Wordpress order by custom field in specific order

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In wordpress How can we fetch records in specific order within meta field value for eg I need to fetch all records where zip code is 60007 first than 60001 than 60003

**In mysql I can easily pass the values in ORDERBY like**

```
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
```

here is what I have now

```
$args = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_key' => 'zip_code',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'suppress_filters' => false,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'paged' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'doctors',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'doctortax',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'dentist'
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'=>'zip_code',
                'value'=> array(60007,60001,60003)
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Sometimes I would prefer to use pure SQL rather than WordPress classes. May be you can try `$wpdb->get_results("your sql query")` ?

Comment: Before doing this I wanted to see if there was any built in functionality , I know I can do it with mysql but my question would help many